# Does the 6.2 kernel support subiquity auto install for ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: server, kernel, 22.04, autoinstall, subiquity

I currently have a working auto installer for Ubuntu 22.04 Server that uses nocloud and will auto setup with a user-data and meta-data folder. This is using the 5.15 kernel which comes with the Ubuntu Server installer.

However, one thing I wanted to try was pre-installing software into the .squashfs of the installer ahead of time so that I don't have to download packages off of the internet either during the cloudinit state or on first boot.

This works, except for when I upgrade the kernel by getting the packages `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`. If I pre-install these into the squashfs to try and get the updated kernel, then when the installer boots up and loads the kernel, it seems to ignore the `nocloud` parameter and instead drops you into the manual installation process.

Once i'm in the UI installer, I can open a new tty session and check the logs in `/var/log/installer` and I can see that subiquity is correctly running and reading my user-data file correctly. However, I can't seem to find any errors located in the logs that would indicate that it should kick out of the autoinstaller and fall back to the manual UI installer.

Comment: FYI:  The HWE kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*jammy*) is now 6.5, ie. `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04      | 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7 | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` with 6.5 being found on *dailies* for a number of days now; not 6.2.  Sorry I can't help with the Server ISOs

Comment: Wow looks like that just happened today! My bad, didn't realize it updated under my nose. I guess that means I need to make sure i'm versioning all my software installs.

Comment: More FYI:  It's Thursday my local (AEST) time, and I noted the 6.5 kernel on Monday this week for *jammy* [Desktop] dailies, they can be built with *-proposed* packages which is I gather why 6.5 was included (for QA purposes its useful; that package now *prompted* was in *proposed* for awhile, and *edge* even longer). 6.5 isn't new for Desktop 22.04 dailies